# Why i am getting this output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g command line and using basic query on default EMPLOYEES table came with 11g :-

```
 SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, 
 EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID
 FROM
 EMPLOYEES
 WHERE
 EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID IN
 (SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID 
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID =
  (SELECT EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID 
   FROM EMPLOYEES 
    WHERE 
    EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME ='Nancy'));
```

==========================================

## OUTPUT

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 MANAGER_ID
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ----------
        109 Daniel               Faviet                           108
        110 John                 Chen                             108
        111 Ismael               Sciarra                          108
        112 Jose Manuel          Urman                            108
        113 Luis                 Popp                             108
        206 William              Gietz                            205
```

6 rows selected.

I am unable to understand why the last row with id=206 is there,whereas the 108 is EMPLOYEE_ID of Nancy which is not related to 206 id.

Comment: 205 must be named Nancy too, no?

Comment: Names are seldom unique in any reasonable sized organisation You must have multiple Nancys. It's probably safer to relate employees my employee_id.

Comment: Please only tag your questions with the actual DB you are using i.e. Oracle, not MySQL

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the representative rows of the `EMPLOYEES` table to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your query finds the managers of all employees named Nancy. Then it goes down *two* levels in the organization hierarchy from those managers and shows those employees.

Comment: Your query returns the set of employees whose manager is **an employee with the same manager as Nancy**. This is not the same as the set of employees who are managed by **an employee managed by Nancy**.

Comment: I don't think 108 is Nancy's ID as we're looking for employees managed by employees manageded by Nancy. 108 and 205 are not Nancy's ID.